# What should be the MySQL query having dynamic group by cluase?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Need MySQL query for below problem

Consider a table having student and their marks in a particular subject

**Schema**

std_id `int(11)`

marks `int(11)`

**Sample data**

```
std_id    marks

1            10
2            15
3            90
4            120
5            25
6            29
7            121
8            122
```

Now I have an web app in which a form will take a input (int) from user.
For eg **12**
then I am required to show total number of student ids (std_id) and their corresponding marks group.

Eg

```
std_total (tot no of students)    group (marks range we got from form)
1                                    0-11
1                                    12-23
2                                    24-35
1                                    84-95
3                                    120-131
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Barmar Your answer was almost correct, I made few changes to clean the output. Your query gives output as  below :

0-11 2

1-12 2

2-13 1

3-14 1

4-15 1

6-17 1

7-18 2

My query return Outout as

0-11 2

12-23 2

24-35 1

36-47 1

48-59 1

72-83 1

84-95 2

```
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(marks/12)*12, '-', FLOOR(marks/12)+11*(FLOOR(marks/12))+11) AS `group`, COUNT(*) as `std_total`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `group`
```

Answer (score 2):

Use division and `FLOOR()` to get the beginning of each range.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(marks/12), '-', FLOOR(marks/12)+11) AS `group`, COUNT(*) as `std_total`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `group`
```

Comment: Extremely thankful. Your answer is foundation to the Khushal's answer